# A href no innerHTML

Tags: html, api, maps

Eu estou usando a API do google pra inserir um mapa no meu site, onde o usuário digita seu CEP, rua, etc, e a API mostra as lojas  credenciadas mais próximas desse usuário, porém eu queria referenciar um link da loja quando ela é mostrada no mapa, atualmente o código que mostra as lojas é esse:

```
  outputDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='espaco' style='margin-left:40px; margin-top:10px'> <a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" +   results[i].title  + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' aproximadamente ' + results[i].duration.text + '<br><hr></div>';
```

Resolvido:

```
 + " <a href = 'goo.gl/maps/sQ5zPMJEERaggz3g8' target= '_blank'>"+results[i].title+"</a></span>"+ "<br>"+
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você possa resolver isso usando uma template string (`entre crases`) e a interpolação (`Olá ${nome}`).

Eu não entendi bem o seu código, mas ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<a href= `google.maps.event.trigger(closest[${results[i].idx_closestMark}])`>
```

Comment: eu consegui resolver, ficou assim: 
+ " <a href = 'https://goo.gl/maps/sQ5zPMJEERaggz3g8'  target= '_blank'>"+results[i].title+"</a></span>"+ "<br>"+